# Using Java, how can I let users set the printer options without using the print dialog?

Tags: java, printing, printer-properties

I am developing an application as a college project. It's (almost) complete, with most features working properly.

The application records visitor information and prints a visitor badge for each visitor. 
The visitor enters their information into the system through a user friendly interface, on completion a visitor badge is automatically printed and their details are saved to a database.

This all works great!! We've already gotten our grades and we got top marks, couldn't be happier!!

However, the printer options on the admin screen are quite limited for the label printer. 
On the admin screen you can search the database and print the results using the typical print dialogue, or you can save the data to a comma delimited CSV file.

All good! But as the label printer only operates from the front end of the program, where there is no print dialogue available, I need to provide access to the printer options on the admin screen then save them for use later when the label printer is in operation. 
At the moment we have the ability to select what printer will be used to print the visitor badges, and we can set and save the page set-up information from the admin page - but I cannot figure out how to access the printer set-up options to provide access to the administrators without using the print dialogue.

Anyone advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i totally got you wrong..:)..Maybe this could help you

[Java Print API](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-10-2000/jw-1020-print.html)

Comment: Wow! thanks for that, it looks really useful!! But it's not what I'm looking for this time. That article focuses on getting what you want printed the way you want it printed. Our application prints everything as it should. I would like to set the printer options, such as selecting a particular tray, setting colour or black and white only printing, colour management, print on one or both sides of the page etc....

Comment: When the administrator selects a printer, I need to be able to check which printer they have selected (I can do this) then provide a screen with the available printer options.